# Unable to find a suitable version for jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, bower-install

Unable to find a suitable version for jquery, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:

```
1) jquery#>=1.9.1 <=2.1.1 which resolved to 2.1.1 and is required by kendo-ui#2016.3.914+Official
2) jquery#2.2.x which resolved to 2.2.4 and is required by angular-seed
3) jquery#1.9.1 - 3 which resolved to 3.1.1 and is required by bootstrap#3.3.7
```

Comment: Please, state your question.

Comment: the question was which version I must choose to work with kendo-ui. Know everything is fine. Thanks for all and thank you @Rory McCrossan for your hint. I had to be clear in asking the question and stating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"resolutions"` to your `bower.json`

```
"resolutions": { 
    "jquery": "2.2.4" 
}
```

This should solve this issue. Not sure if kendo-ui will be ok with 2.2.x. It probably depends on your target browsers. Bootstrap typically has no issues.

Comment: thanks.. this worked for me, I also used a newer version jquery 3.1.1 and everything is ok